# Geometry-Preserving Isomorphisms $\bigwedge V \to \bigwedge V^*$ and Defining the Regressive Product

Tags: linear-algebra, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

$
\newcommand\Ext\bigwedge
\newcommand\pair[1]{\langle#1\rangle}
\newcommand\tensor\otimes
\newcommand\Iso\mathscr
\newcommand\intrsym\lrcorner
\newcommand\intr{{\,\intrsym\,}}
\DeclareMathOperator\span{span}
$

My actual question is towards the bottom, bolded.
The rest of this is context.

## Geometry-Preserving Isomorphisms

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional vector space,
$V^*$ it dual, and $\Ext V$ its exterior algebra.
I am primarily interested in $V = \mathbb R^n$,
but I don't think that makes much difference here.

We identify $\Ext V^*$ with $(\Ext V)^*$ in the usual way:
for $v_1,\dotsc,v_k \in V$ and $\alpha_1,\dotsc,\alpha_k \in V^*$ define
$$
  \pair{\alpha_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\alpha_k, v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge b_k}
= \det(M),\quad
  M_{ij} = \pair{\alpha_i, v_j},
$$
where $\pair{\alpha_i, v_j}$ is the natural pairing,
and we extend by linearity to the entirety of $\Ext V^*\tensor\Ext V$,
defining $\pair{\cdot,\cdot}$ to be zero when the grades don't match.
We will not distinguish between $\Ext V^*$ and $(\Ext V)^*$.

We can identify (up to a scalar multiple) simple $k$-vectors $A \in \Ext^k V$
with subspaces of $V$ by
$$
  A^\wedge := \{v \in V \;:\; v\wedge A = 0\},
$$
and we can show that (up to a scalar)
there is a unique simple $\alpha \in \Ext^{n-k}V^*$ such that
$$
  \alpha^\intrsym := \{v \in V \;:\; v\intr\alpha)\} = A^\wedge,
\tag{$*$}
$$
where $\intrsym$ is the *interior product*,
which we'll define for both multivectors and dual multivectors by
$$
  \pair{\xi, X\wedge Y} = \pair{X\intr\xi, Y},\quad
  \pair{\xi\wedge\zeta, X} = \pair{\zeta, \xi\intr X}
$$
for all $\xi, \zeta \in \Ext V^*$ and $X, Y \in \Ext V$.
The exterior products then correspond to spans and intersections
of subspaces of $V$:
$$\begin{aligned}
  (A\wedge B)^\wedge &= \begin{cases}
    \{0\}
      &\text{if }\,\exists v\in V\setminus\{0\}.\,
      v \in A^\wedge\text{ and }v \in B^\wedge,
  \\
    \span(A^\wedge\cup B^\wedge)
      &\text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}
\\
  (\alpha\wedge\beta)^\intrsym &= \begin{cases}
    \{0\}
      &\text{if }\,\exists H\subset V.\,
      H\text{ is a hyperplane and }
      \alpha^\intrsym \subseteq H\text{ and }\beta^\intrsym \subseteq H,
  \\
    \alpha^\intr\cap B^\intr
      &\text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}
\end{aligned}$$
for any simple $A, B \in \Ext V$ and simple $\alpha, \beta \in \Ext V^*$.
Call these equations ($**$).

A *geometry-preserving isomorphism* $\Iso I : \Ext V \to \Ext V^*$
is such that (1) if $A$ is simple then $\Iso I(A)$ is simple,
and (2) $A^\wedge = (\Iso I(A))^\intrsym$ for simple $A$.
We will abbreviate "geometry-preserving isomorphism" to "GP-isomorphism".
(I do acknowledge the possibility
that there may be a better definition of "geometry-preserving"
that captures the same spirit,
and would not mind that as a means of answering my question.)

Two particular GP-isomorphisms of interest are the *Poincaré isomorphisms*.
Choose $I \in \Ext^n V$.
Since $\Ext^n V$ and $\Ext^n V^*$ are 1-dimensional,
there is a unique $I^* \in \Ext^n V^*$ such that $\pair{I^*, I} = 1$.
We then define $I^\# : \Ext V \to \Ext V^*$ and $I_\# : \Ext V^* \to \Ext V$ by
$$
  I^\#(X) = X\intr I^*,\quad I_\#(\xi) = \xi\intr I.
$$
We can show that
$$
  (I^\#)^{-1} = I_\#^*,\quad I_\#^{-1} = (I^\#)^*,\quad
  (xI)^\# = \frac1xI^\#,\quad (xI)_\# = xI_\#,
$$
where here $*$ denotes the dual of a transformation and $x$ is a scalar.

## Why Should We Prefer $I^\#$ and $I_\#$?

**My main interest** is in defining the *regressive product*
$\vee : \Ext V\tensor\Ext V \to \Ext V$,
which is usually done by
$$
  X\vee Y := (I^\#)^{-1}(I^\#(X)\wedge I^\#(Y)).
$$
Because $I^\#$ is geometry-preserving,
$\vee$ corresponds to the intersection of subspaces
just like $\wedge$ does over $\Ext V^*$.
We can show that using $I_\#^{-1}$ instead of $I^\#$
results in the same product.

But let's take a step back and work ourselves towards a definition of $\vee$.
Given any three GP-isomorphisms
$\Iso M, \Iso L, \Iso R : \Ext V \to \Ext V^*$
we could define
$$
  X\vee_{\Iso M,\Iso L,\Iso R} Y := \Iso M^{-1}(\Iso L(X)\wedge\Iso R(Y)).
$$
However, upon requiring that $\vee_{\Iso M,\Iso L,\Iso R}$ have an identity $E$,
$$
  X\vee_{\Iso M,\Iso L,\Iso R} E = E\vee_{\Iso M,\Iso L,\Iso R} X = X,
$$
we can show that it suffices to take $\Iso M = \Iso L = \Iso R$
(and so we will simply write $\vee_{\Iso M}$).
Note that this also automatically gives us associativity of $\vee_{\Iso M}$.

So we need only find a single suitable GP-isomorphism.

The correspondence ($*$) above
tells us that a GP-isomorphism must be grade reversing,
i.e. grade $k$ maps to $n-k$.
Not only that,
but since all Poincaré isomorphisms are multiples of each other
(and every multiple of a Poincaré isomorphism is Poincaré)
this correspondence also tells us that the restriction of any GP-isomorphism
to a space of simple $k$-vectors must be Poincaré;
i.e. for any GP-isomorphism $\Iso I$ and $S \subseteq \Ext^k V$
a one-dimensional subspace of simple $k$-vectors,
there is $I \in \Ext^n V$ such that $\Iso I|_S = I^\#|_S$.
(It is interesting to note that if our field is $\mathbb F_2$,
then the only GP-isomorphism is the unique Poincaré isomorphism.)
But it appears to me that this is the only restriction.
For example, define $\Iso I = I^\#$ on $k$-vectors for $k \not= 2$
and $\Iso I = xI^\#$ on $2$-vectors for some $x \not= 0, 1$.
This acts like a Poincaré isomorphism on each grade individually,
but isn't one when considered on the entirety of $\Ext V$,
Additionally, $X\vee_{\Iso I} Y \not= X\vee Y$ in general:
If $n = 4$, $A \in \Ext^2 V$, and $B \in \Ext^3 V$ then
$$
  A\vee_{\Iso I} B
= \Iso I^{-1}(\Iso I(A)\wedge\Iso I(B))
= (I^\#)^{-1}(xI^\#(A)\wedge I^\#(B))
= xA\vee B,
$$
noting that $I^\#(A)\wedge I^\#(B) \in \Ext^3 V^*$ and $3 \not= 4-2$.

**So this is my question: *solely* with an eye towards defining $\vee$,
is there any reason to prefer the Poincaré isomorphisms**
(or perhaps some other isomorphism)
**over any other geometry-preserving isomorphism?
I.e., do the Poincaré isomorphisms give $\vee$ some desirable property
that other geometry-preserving isomorphisms do not?**

---

I am aware that
$$
  X\wedge Y = \pair{I^\#(X), Y}I,\quad
  \xi\wedge\zeta = \pair{\zeta, I_\#(\xi)}I^*.
$$
which give $I^\#$ and $I_\#$ another interpretation
as coming from bilinear forms induced by the exterior product.
Fixing a non-degenerate quadratic form $Q$ on $V$
(and now assuming characteristic $\not=2$)
endows $\Ext V$ with the corresponding Clifford product,
and the isomorphism $\Iso Q : V \to V^*$ from $Q$
extends by the universal property of Clifford algebras
to a Clifford algebra isomorphism $\Ext V \to \Ext V^*$.
I am then also aware that
$$
  (\Iso Q^{-1}\circ I^\#)(X) = I^{-1}X,\quad
  (I_\#\circ\Iso Q)(X) = \widetilde XI,
$$
where $I^{-1}$ is the Clifford inverse of $I$,
$\widetilde X$ is the reversal of $X$ (i.e. main anti-involution),
and $I^{-1}X$ and $\widetilde XI$ are Clifford products.

These properties are very, very nice
and make the Poincaré isomorphisms desirable;
however, I am *specifically* curious
as to whether they are special for defining $\vee$.