# Geometric interpretation of intersection product

Tags: exterior-algebra, intersection-theory, poincare-duality

Let $E,E^*$ be a pair of dual $n$-dimensional real vector spaces and let $e,e^*$ be a pair of dual basis vectors of $\bigwedge^n E$ and $\bigwedge^n E^*$, respectively. For $u,v\in\bigwedge E$, we can define an "intersection product" by
$$u\cap v=D^e[(D^e)^{-1}u\wedge(D^e)^{-1}v]\tag{1}$$
where $D^e:\bigwedge E^*\to\bigwedge E$ is the Poincaré duality map given by $D^e u^*=i(u^*)e$ where $i$ is the insertion operator. This product makes $\bigwedge E$ into an associative, unital, anti-commutative algebra (the "intersection algebra").

**Question:** Is there a simple geometric interpretation of the product in (1), analogous to the geometric interpretation of the wedge product in terms of volume? By "simple" I mean using basic concepts of linear and exterior algebra and not more advanced theories (manifolds, homology, cohomology, etc.).

My thoughts so far:

- When I first saw the name "intersection product" I thought maybe when $u$ is a $p$-blade representing a subspace $U$ of $E$ and $v$ is a $q$-blade representing a subspace $V$ of $E$, then $u\cap v$ would represent the intersection $U\cap V$, but that's clearly not right since $u\cap v$ has degree $p+q-n$. If $p+q=n$, then $u\cap v$ is a scalar and $u\cap v\ne 0$ if and only if $E=U\oplus V$, with the sign of $u\cap v$ describing the relative orientations of $U$, $V$, and $E$.
- The intersection algebra in $\bigwedge E$ is isomorphic to the exterior algebra in $\bigwedge E^*$, so maybe this leads to a simple geometric description.
- If $E$ is an oriented Euclidean space with oriented unit volume $e$, then we can take $E^*=E$ under the inner product and Poincaré duality reduces to Hodge duality, which may also lead to a simple description.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\newcommand\Ext{{\bigwedge}}
$

Yes. Let $A, B \in \Ext E$ be simple multivectors, i.e. products of vectors. We can associate each such simple multivector with a subspace of $E$ by
$$
  [A] := \{x \in E \;:\; x\wedge A = 0\}.
$$
Now let $H$ be the set of all hyperplanes of $E$, which could be expressed as
$$
  H := \{\ker\phi \;:\; \phi \in E^*\}.
$$
We may then derive that
$$
  [A\wedge B] = \begin{cases}
    \{0\} &\text{if }\exists x\in E.\:x \in [A]\text{ and }x \in [B],
  \\
    [A]\oplus [B] &\text{otherwise},
  \end{cases}
$$
and
$$
  [A\vee B] = \begin{cases}
    \{0\} &\text{if }\exists U\in H.\:[A]\subseteq U\text{ and }[B]\subseteq U,
  \\
    [A]\cap [B] &\text{otherwise}.
  \end{cases}
$$
By $[A]\oplus[B]$ I specifically mean the span of $[A]\cup[B]$.

Comment: What do you mean by $A\vee B$?

Comment: @blargoner Oh, I'm sorry, I guess didn't read your question carefully enough. That's the intersection product. So $A\vee B = A\cap B$ in your notation.

Comment: Thanks, I'm going to digest your answer for a bit. Just curious, what references have you found useful for this material?

Comment: @blargoner From your notation, I would guess you're already reading Greub's *Multilinear Algebra* (1967). The intersection product is often used in the context of [geometric algebra](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_algebra), which is essentially viewing Clifford algebras as a product on the exterior algebra. I see that Hestenes and Sobczyk's *Clifford Algebra to Geometric Calculus* (1984) has some paragraphs on the intersection product, but I will warn you that this is a very impenetrable text...

Comment: ...I think that Mandolesi's [*Compendium on Multivector Contractions*](http://arxiv.org/abs/2205.07608) (2022) is worth taking a look at; section 6 discusses various types of subspaces that multivectors represent. I will also note that the above perspective on the intersection product is fundamental to *projective/plane-based geometric algebra* (PGA); see Charles Gunn's PhD thesis [*Geometry, Kinematics, and Rigid Body Mechanics in Cayley-Klein Geometries*](https://depositonce.tu-berlin.de/handle/11303/3355) (2011) as well as his other works...

Comment: ...It is also important in *conformal geometric algebra* (CGA) where it can be used to intersect (generalized) spheres in any dimension; see for example Doran and Lasenby's *Geometric Algebra for Physicists* (2003), though there are many other possible references since CGA is particularly popular in applications. Doran and Lasenby do not refer to the intersection product directly though...

Comment: ...If $I$ is an $n$-vector and we consider a non-degenerate Clifford algebra on $E$ then $$A\vee B = I^{-1}[(IA)\wedge(IB)] = A\mathbin{{\lfloor}}(IB)$$ where ${\lfloor}$ is the *right contraction* (a manifestation of the metric), and in fact the map $A \mapsto IA$ is the Clifford algebra realization of $(D^I)^*$.

Comment: See also my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4494365/geometry-preserving-isomorphisms-bigwedge-v-to-bigwedge-v-and-defining-th

Comment: Thanks for the references! Yes, I'm reading Greub (1978), but he doesn't provide much geometric motivation or intuition.

Comment: I discovered that Greub has exactly what I was looking for in Proposition VI, subsection 6.30 of *Multilinear Algebra* (1967). I can't believe he deleted this material from the next edition!

Comment: @blargoner Well, that is quite unfortunate. In the 1978 edition it appears there is a partial result at the end of subsection 6.12 which only considers $p$- and $q$-vectors where $p+q$ is the dimension of the space, but indeed I don't see the general result (even as an exercise).